# Draw pencil-stroke like line in Gimp

Tags: gimp, tutorial, stroke

I found this pencil stroke is very fancy and I wondered how it can be emulated in Gimp or Photoshop.

Actually I found **pencil drawing** is really fascinating and I hope to learn more about it.

I will greatly appreciate any:

1. tutorials on how to make this kind of drawing
2. similar works so that I feel the beauty

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a crayon brush. You can download a similar brush for GIMP [here](http://pstogimpbrushes.deviantart.com/art/sanami276-s-crayonees-31072970) or the same brush set for Photoshop [here](http://sanami276.deviantart.com/art/Crayon-doodles-PS7-29351533)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is paper, natural media, and a scanner. It's not as efficient but if you want the effect to look really good, this is going to net the best results.

Of course, you can also follow that method to create your own brushes or pick up the work of others who have done the same (see John's links). The more you stretch the brush artwork from it's original scale, the less convincing the effect will be.

**This is my workflow when creating a custom natural media brush** (in Illustrator or Photoshop).

1. Set up the basic layout with scale and proportions as you want them
2. Print it out at roughly the right scale
3. Overlay it with a sheet of layout paper (like [Graphics 360](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001KZH1QK))
4. Experiment on a few sheets with various implements until you get the effect you want
5. Scan the best results
6. Create brushes *-OR-* just use the sketches as positioned objects/layers

That is obviously more time consuming than (1) downloading a brush set and (2) using it. But, when done well the results are noticeably improved ... and unique to your project!